# Node.js + MongoLab on Azure, how to prevent web site from being idle?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, web

I deploy my node.js + MongoDB app to an Azure Web Site, I use MongoDB with the MongoLab add-on.

I noticed that the first request I send to the app after each deploy does not work, because the site gets initialized only on the first request, and that is the time when the connection to MongoDB is built up.

And another problem is that if I do not use the site for a while, then it seems to be put in an idle state, because the first time I try to access it again, it does not work, similarly to the first request.

Is there any way to force Azure to start the web site after a deploy and to prevent it from putting the web site to sleep?

**UPDATE**: I have switched the web site from **free** to **standard**, which seemed to solve the second problem, it does not seem to be put into sleep any more.

The first problem persists, I put a console.log() call at the beginning of my app.js, and monitored the site with `azure site log tail`. The app.js got executed only on the first request. However, this is not a big problem, because naturally I try to open the site after every deploy in the browser, but still, it's a bit strange.

Comment: I have seen this before but not had a chance to ask around. Will forward this.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 1):

To warm up the site after deployment, if you are leveraging Azure Web Sites source control support one option to consider is a post deployment action hook with an HTTP client command. More information is available at this link: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks.

To prevent the web site from being unloaded during idle time, you can enable the Always On setting for a site in Standard mode. More information is available at this link: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure.